# Realm relation field always null

Tags: android, null, realm, relation

There are my models:

```
public class RChat extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String              Id;
    private RMyTest Test;

    public RChat() {}
}
```

and

```
public class RMyTest extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String myName;

    public RMyTest() {
    }
}
```

And I'm using like this:

```
mRealm = Realm.getInstance(this);


        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        final RChat chat = mRealm.createObject(RChat.class);
        chat.setId("test");
        RMyTest rProfile = mRealm.createObject(RMyTest.class);
        rProfile.setMyName("alireza test");
        chat.setTest(rProfile);
        //mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chat);
        mRealm.commitTransaction();

        RChat chat1 = mRealm.where(RChat.class).equalTo("Id","test").findFirst();
```

but the `chat1` object's `Test` field has null value always. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: A side note, how are you getting the code to compile without having setters and getters for your `RealmObject`s?

Comment: Your code works fine with me btw.

Comment: Same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @toidiu I posted the answer. Please check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking my objects must not be null directly but the point is Realm uses proxy for models and the proxy is not null actually.

Answer (score 10):

The code looks correct. If you get null by examine the `chat1`'s `Test` field in the debug window, you will get a null value. That is expected.

Realm will generate a proxy class and override the getters/setters in the proxy class. So if you try

```
RMyTest rProfile = chat1.getTest();
```

I am sure you can get the corresponding `RMyTest` Object instead of `null`.

This behaviour is documented [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging).

Comment: Using getters helped. The only answer in internet that helped me!