# RealmObject returns null fields

Tags: realm

Writing to realm:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mContext);
realm.beginTransaction();
InfoCocktail content = (InfoCocktail) response.body();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(content);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

and when reading

```
InfoCocktail cocktail = realm.where(InfoCocktail.class).equalTo("id", mCocktailId).findFirst();
```

i see value using debug mode

```
InfoCocktail = [{id:1},{ingredients:RealmList<Ingredient>[5]},{alc:20},{name:test},{image:http:url},{story:}]
```

but

all InfoCocktail  fields are null

how can i fix this?

```
public class InfoCocktail extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private RealmList<Ingredient> ingredients;
private String alc;
private String name;
private String image;
private String story;
 public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public RealmList<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}
public void setIngredients(RealmList<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}
```

.... and other fields getters and setters

Comment: Please show your `InfoCocktail` class. I suspect your forget to type `dynamic` before properties declarations.

Comment: I've added InfoCocktail class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966955/realm-relation-field-always-null/32983540#32983540 Please check this answer.

Comment: thanks, that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use Stirng.valueOf(object.getField()) it works for me

```
String.valueOf(infoCocktail.getName());
```